# Weird errors on Prime Number &twins code?

Tags: java, primes

So I'm doing this Prime Numbers homework assignment and given a good example I think I've got most of that part down. The one thing I struggle with is an error at the line that says "public static void sieve (int n)" that also occurs at "private static int twinPrime()"

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeNumbers
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter a value for n: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine(); // clear input buffer
    System.out.println();
    
    // Generate a list of prime numbers between 2 and n
    // to test Part 1
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = sieve(n);
    System.out.println("Prime numbers between 2 and " + n + ":\n");
    System.out.println(primes);
    System.out.println();
    
    // Test Part 2
    System.out.println("The twin primes less than " + n + " are:\n");
    twins(n);
    System.out.println();
}

// COMPLETE THIS METHOD FOR PART 1
public static ArrayList<Integer> sieve (int maxValue)
{
    public static void sieve (int n)
    {
        // 1 = assumed prime, 0 = known not prime
        // Create a list of numbers from 0-n
        ArrayList<Integer> sieve =
                         new ArrayList<Integer>(n+1);
        // Fill initial sieve with non-zeros (assumed prime)
        int index;
        
        for (index = 0; index <= n; index++)
        {
            sieve.add(index);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Starting sieve: " + sieve);
        
        // For each position/value >= 2, if it's 1,
        // cross off its later multiples (set them to 0)
        for (index = 2; index < sieve.size(); index++)
        {
            if (sieve.get(index) > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(index + " is prime");
                
                // Mark off multiples of index
                int mult = 2 * index; // first multiple
                for (; mult < (n+1); mult += index)
                {
                    // Increment by (index) each time
                    // set() takes position, new value
                    sieve.set(mult, 0); // mark off value
                }
                System.out.println(sieve);
            }
        }
        
        // Remove all non-prime values
        sieve.remove(0);
        sieve.remove(0);
        
        for (index = 0; index < sieve.size(); index++)
        {
            if (sieve.get(index) == 0)
            {
                sieve.remove(index);
                index--;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(sieve);
    
}}

// COMPLETE THIS METHOD FOR PART 2
public static void twins (int max)
{
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}
}
```

Here are the errors:

> void is an invalid type for the variable sieve
>
> Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
>
> Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

and

> Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
>
> Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatements
>
> Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
>
> Syntax error on token "int", @ expected

I've just never seen anything like this before? And I don't know where to start looking for an explanation? I can probably fix the code myself if someone can explain the errors to me!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare a method inside another method:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sieve (int maxValue)
{
    public static void sieve (int n)
    {
```

In Java, this isn't allowed, hence the error.

You need to figure out which of the two declarations it is you want, and get rid of the other one (not forgetting the remove the closing curly brace).